# Value of type 'XPathObject' has no member 'text'

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath, kanna

I am trying to replicate the for loop without using a loop, which works and is commented out.

How can I access the text member without using a `for` loop?

```
if let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(html: htmlText, encoding: .utf8)
{
    for item in doc.css("div[class^='test']")
    {
        print("item: \(count)")                                           
        let itemName = item.css("p[class^='hello']")
        /*
        for itemName in item.css(("p[class^='hello']"))
        {
            print(itemName.text!)
        }
        */
        print(itemName.text!) // error here
        count += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by doing print(itemName.first!.text!).

Gets the first xmlelement.